# How/where can a U.S. resident buy recently issued Chinese 3-month Treasury bills?

Tags: united-states, investing, bonds, china

[According to Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/11/14/us-imf-china-yuan-idUSKCN0T22OC20151114#7t5xf6b3ombq16Fg.97):

> China has rolled out a flurry of reforms recently to liberalize its
>   markets and also help the yuan meet the IMF's checklist, including
>   scrapping a ceiling on deposit rates, **issuing three-month Treasury
>   bills weekly** and improving the transparency of Chinese data.

The US Treasury has a site where people can set up an account and buy USTs, but I can't find this for China.  Does anyone know how an American can buy Chinese Yuan Treasuries?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to continue updating this answer because I'd like to buy the bonds directly, and avoid using ETFs or MFs that charge fees.  I haven't found a way to do this, yet part of being in the SDR basket is having an internationally open bond market, so this makes little sense.

So far, one ETF I've found is CHNB, which is 80% Chinese Renminbi bonds.  It appears from reading the [fact sheet](http://www.globalxfunds.com/CHNB/FS) that the government bonds are primarily long.

[Chinese Treasury site](http://www.mof.gov.cn/index.htm)?  I'm going to have to learn Mandarin.

Comment: China has some interesting banking rules.  You might not be able to even purchase debt from the government without being approved first.  I've only taken a few primer courses on their banking system and haven't come across anything.